# Receiving multiple incoming messages for a single send

Tags: sockets, visual-c++, udp, winsock

I'm working on a simple UDP messaging system and I've got it mostly working. The structure is to have 1 server that simply broadcasts messages to all clients listening on a specific port (its just for use on a LAN or ad-hoc network not connected to the internet, although my test PC is currently plugged into the web). My problem is that every time I send a message the client receives 2 copies. At the moment I'm not setting the target IP as the subnet, so maybe this is the problem:

(Note: I know I'm violating the standard client-server terminology, because my "client" is binding a specific port, but bear with me).

So here is how my server specifies the target data:

```
   d_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

   if(d_socket == -1)
   {
      printf("\nError in creating socket");
      return false;
   }

   //socket option set to 1 because we are setting the SO_BROADCAST setting to true
   //MSDN says to use int for boolean option types.
   int l_socket_option = 1;

   setsockopt(d_socket, 
              SOL_SOCKET, 
              SO_BROADCAST, 
              (char*)&l_socket_option, 
              sizeof(int));

   //Zero out the broadcast address member to initialize it
   memset(&d_broadcast_address,
          0, 
          sizeof(d_broadcast_address));

   //Specify that 
   d_broadcast_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
   d_broadcast_address.sin_port = htons(34444);
   d_broadcast_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST;
```

My client opens the port like so:

```
d_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

   //Set port so that calls to recvfrom do not block. Instead recvfrom returns an error if no data is present now.
   u_long l_no_block_specifier = 1;
   int l_socket_control_result = ioctlsocket(d_socket,
                                             FIONBIO,
                                             &l_no_block_specifier);

   if(d_socket == -1)
   {
      printf("\nError in creating socket");
      return false;
   }

   //Zero out the broadcast address member to initialize it
   memset(&d_server_address,
          0, 
          sizeof(d_server_address));

   //Specify that 
   d_server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
   d_server_address.sin_port = htons(34444);
   d_server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

   d_address_length = sizeof(d_server_address);

   //Bind socket and print an error if bind fails.
   if ( bind(d_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&d_server_address, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) != 0 )
   {
      printf("\nError in binding socket");
   }
```

After the ports are opened the client spawns a thread to repetitively read the port. I wrote a small test app that just sends an integer every representing the sequence of the message. The output of that program is as below:

> ```
> Sending message #0 at time = 4.0
> Got message #0 at time = 4.0
> Got message #0 at time = 25.0
> Sending message #1 at time = 1004.0
> Got message #1 at time = 1004.0
> Got message #1 at time = 1047.0
> Got message #2 at time = 2004.0
> Sending message #2 at time = 2004.0
> Got message #2 at time = 2064.0
> Sending message #3 at time = 3005.0
> Got message #3 at time = 3005.0
> Got message #3 at time = 3086.0
> ```

I've tested it pretty thoroughly and am sure that the program itself isn't accidentally printing out 2 notifications for each message (besides the timestamp shows the belated arrival between the 2 receipts).

Why does this happen? I'm guessing that it is because my test PC is hooked up to the internet and therefore the message gets routed through 2 different paths back to my own PC due to the broadcast.

**EDIT:**

I changed the client so that it binds the broadcast port using its own IP address instead of specifying INADDR_ANY and this stopped the duplicate receipts. I also updated the server to broadcast only on the subnet it is a part of, but I don't think this had impact on the multiple receipts.

Comment: You did not show your actual sending or reading code, but I would guess that since you are sending to `INADDR_BROADCAST` (255.255.255.255) instead of a specific subnet broadcast address, and are binding the receiver to `INADDR_ANY` (0.0.0.0) instead of a specific NIC, chances are you are receiving multiple copies of each message from different NICs on the receiver. You can use [`WSARecvMsg()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741687.aspx) instead of `recvfrom()` to determine which NIC is actually receiving each packet.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't paste the sending/receiving code, because that would have been a lot. When I do ipconfig I see that I have 2 IP addresses, 1 from the "Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection" and the other from the "Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection". So I'm guessing that the extra message comes from the fact that I have 2 IP targets on my machine for the message to hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the client so that it binds the broadcast port using its own IP address instead of specifying INADDR_ANY and this stopped the duplicate receipts. I also updated the server to broadcast only on the subnet it is a part of, but I don't think this had impact on the multiple receipts. –  Ian